# Javascript canvas check if all recs on the screen overlap a new one

Tags: collision-detection, javascript, html-canvas

So I know the AABB collision detection formula, however, this code does not work. Whenever I press space, a new square pops up. But this new square can spawn inside another, something that I do not want to happen. Here is a snippet of the code I think is going wrong:

```
var xTopsBotsYTopsBotsSquares = [];

//Makes a randint() function.
function randint(min, max) {

    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function checkForOccupiedAlready(left, top, right, bottom) {

    if (xTopsBotsYTopsBotsSquares.length == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < xTopsBotsYTopsBotsSquares.length; i++) {
        var data = xTopsBotsYTopsBotsSquares[i];

        if (data[0] <= right || data[1] <= bottom ||
            data[2] >= left  || data[3] >= top) {/*Do nothing*/} 
        else {

            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

//Makes a new square
function makeNewsquare() {
    var checkingIfRepeatCords = true;
    //DO loop that checks if there is a repeat.
    do {
        //Makes the square x/y positions 
        var squareRandomXPos = randint(50, canvas.width - 50);
        var squareRandomYPos = randint(50, canvas.height - 50);

        //Tests if that area is already occupied
        if (checkForOccupiedAlready(squareRandomXPos, 
                                    squareRandomYPos, 
                                    squareRandomXPos+50, 
                                    squareRandomYPos+50) == true) {

            xTopsBotsYTopsBotsSquares.push([squareRandomXPos, 
                                            squareRandomYPos, 
                                            squareRandomXPos+50, 
                                            squareRandomYPos+50]);
            console.log(squareRandomXPos, squareRandomYPos, squareRandomXPos+50, squareRandomYPos+50);
            checkingIfRepeatCords = false;
        }
    }
    while (checkingIfRepeatCords == true);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
if (data[0] <= right || data[1] <= bottom ||
    data[2] >= left  || data[3] >= top)
```

should be:

```
if (data[0] <= right && data[1] <= bottom &&
    data[2] >= left  && data[3] >= top)
```

RULE:
| |    ----->OR
&& --> AND

Comment: No problem :) you are welcome.